# Run two concurrent themes in one installation

Tags: child-theme, blog-page, switch-theme

I'm trying to add a 'blog' to my established and customized wordpress installation. Goal is to have a blog page that runs a child theme of TwentyTwenty, pulling any post of the category "blog-posts"

I currently our blog running on a different wordpress installation, but for various reasons, including database unity, I'd like to merge my primary domain (sequoiawaste.com) with my blog.sequoiawaste.com installation, and let visitors browse at sequoiawaste.com/blog

Thats not a complicated matter at all, I just did a standard Export/Import. Its the formatting/presentation that I'm struggling with.

I would GREATLY prefer to stick with a child theme of TwentyTwenty for the blog, but maintain the custom theme that organizes the rest of the site...

It does not seem that this is a common or even remotely encouraged thing to do in the WP community. I've tried a few plugins that claim to override the Theme for Pages or Posts, but they do not respect a child theme what so ever, and I'm not interested in some of TwentyTwenty's less-than-optimal defaults **cough Header/footer**

Does anyone have some guidance here?

I need to avoid Multisite due to financial reasons (my host charges 10x more for that, and its totally unnecessary given my small audience). Child Themes dont technically work here, because my default parent theme is *not* TwentyTwenty... and I simply cannot find a plugin that can help properly here. Most can override a single page, but something like /blog/page/2 comes across with no formatting, etc etc.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not impossible, juggling themes like that is quite fragile and rarely used out of special contexts (development, theme demo's, etc).

In your situation I would probably just consolidate it on one theme and conditionally output different stylesheet for the section of the site that needs it. It would not be hugely different in result, but much simpler and reliable in code.

Comment: Thanks Rarst. Instead I just 'flip-flopped' my org. I set its default theme to the TwentyTwenty for the Blog (where I'd like to continually edit and push content), and manually overrode all of my site content that I currently have to the custom theme. It got the job done, and I think I'll leave the heavy lifting until we decide to overhaul the whole deal, as I dont think stylesheets would get me far enough.